# Get the author meta adds <p> now

Tags: post-meta, author

I used to have this code which worked fine:

```
<div class="kabaut"><?php echo get_the_author_meta('description'); ?></div>
```

After the latest update, wordpress now adds `<p> </p>` tags for the output. How do I strip out these tags?

Comment: try using the get_the_author_description filter to strip out the <p> tags

Comment: you can remove this with `remove_filter("get_the_author_description", "wpautop");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_the_author_meta` applies a filter `get_the_author_{$field}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/#source), i.e. in your case it will be `get_the_author_description`:

```
function stripp($value) {
    return str_replace(array('<p>','</p>'), '', $value);
}
add_filter('get_the_author_description', 'stripp');
```

In case the `p` tag has attributes, you may have to modify the above accordingly, or use `preg_replace`.